# Mariasql not accepting more than 3MB base64 image file

Tags: node.js, base64, mariasql

I am unable to upload image file as base64 into DB when file size is more than 3MB.

I am using mariasql v0.2.6 node module.

To store base64 I am using column type LONGTEXT. it saves base64 if the file is less than 3MB but it fails if size exceeds 3MB.

There is no payload error because I set body parser json limit to 50mb but it fails with below error when file size exceeds 3MB. Actual file size is 4074247 bytes

```
  node: ../src/binding.cc:992: static void      Client::cb_poll(uv_poll_t*, int, int): Assertion `status == 0' failed.
   Aborted
```

Body parser limit set to 50mb

```
  app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}))
  app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override'));
```

My mariasql db connection config

```
  var Client = require('mariasql');

  var c = new Client({
      host: config.mdbConfig.host,
      user: config.mdbConfig.user,
      password: config.mdbConfig.password,
      db: config.mdbConfig.db,
      multiStatements: true
   });

 module.exports=c;
```

I went through everything in Stack Overflow related to this but none of them helped me fix this issue.

Comment: Have you considered changing the maria db driver?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mariadb

Another thing causing the issue may also be your text format. Have you tried UTF-8?

Comment: Nope I didn’t try with that driver yet. Do you mean column type collation to utf-8?

Comment: Concert the text to utf8. I read somewhere that would solve done issues though I can't remember where...

Comment: Ok leme try that

Comment: converting to utf8 also didn't work for me